# uml Composition relationships to RDF and OWL

Tags: uml, rdf, owl

I'm beginner in RDF and OWL ontologies.

I'm trying to transform this diagram into OWL syntax.

[image]

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
        >

    <!-- OWL Class Definition - Robot Position -->
    <owl:Class rdf:ID="house" />
            <owl:Class rdf:ID="room" />
            <owl:Class rdf:ID="kitchen" />
            <owl:Class rdf:ID="garden" />
            <owl:Class rdf:ID="table" />
            <owl:Class rdf:ID="chair" />

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:ID="composedBy">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#house"/>
        <rdfs:rang rdf:resource="#room" >
    </owl:ObjectProperty>              
</rdf:RDF>
```

I don't know how to do to make the composed by relation used many times.
I'm thinking to make the range to take in a collection type with

`(house)---composedBy---(room, kitchen, garden)`

but, I want to use the same relation with

`(kitchen)---comoposedBy---(table, chair)`

The validator is making an error because I used composedBy as an ID twice. (I removed it now)

How can I do to translate this diagram correctly.

:))

Comment: To be clear, are you trying to say that "every thing that a home has is either a room, a kitchen, or a garden" (unionOf works here), or that "a home must have a room, must have a kitchen, and must have a garden" (unionof doesn't work here)?

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to say that a House must have a (or at least one) Kitchen, and must have a (or at least one) Room, and must have a (or at least one) Garden, then unionOf isn't really solving the issue here.  Rather than worrying about the range of the composition property, I think it might be more helpful if you have a more generic component property, and express the different relationships that must hold by using existential restrictions.  E.g., you could say that

> House ⊑ =1 hasPart.Kitchen
>   House ⊑ ≥2 hasPart.Room
>   House ⊑ ∃hasPart.Garden

to say that a House has exactly one Kitchen, at least two Room, and at least one Garden. Similarly, you could say that has a table and a chair with

> Kitchen ⊑ ∃hasPart.Chair
>   Kitchen ⊑ ∃hasPart.Table

In Protégé, this would look like:

[image: house ontology, kitchen class with axioms]

The RDF serialization in Turtle and RDF/XML are:

```
@prefix :      <http://www.example.org/houses#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

<http://www.example.org/houses>
        a       owl:Ontology .

:hasPart  a     owl:ObjectProperty .

:Table  a       owl:Class .
:Room   a       owl:Class .
:Garden  a      owl:Class .
:Chair  a       owl:Class .

:House  a                owl:Class ;
        rdfs:subClassOf  [ a                            owl:Restriction ;
                           owl:minQualifiedCardinality  "2"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger ;
                           owl:onClass                  :Room ;
                           owl:onProperty               :hasPart
                         ] ;
        rdfs:subClassOf  [ a                   owl:Restriction ;
                           owl:onProperty      :hasPart ;
                           owl:someValuesFrom  :Garden
                         ] ;
        rdfs:subClassOf  [ a                         owl:Restriction ;
                           owl:onClass               :Kitchen ;
                           owl:onProperty            :hasPart ;
                           owl:qualifiedCardinality  "1"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger
                         ] .


:Kitchen  a              owl:Class ;
        rdfs:subClassOf  [ a                   owl:Restriction ;
                           owl:onProperty      :hasPart ;
                           owl:someValuesFrom  :Table
                         ] ;
        rdfs:subClassOf  [ a                   owl:Restriction ;
                           owl:onProperty      :hasPart ;
                           owl:someValuesFrom  :Chair
                         ] .
```

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns="http://www.example.org/houses#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.example.org/houses"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.example.org/houses#Room"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.example.org/houses#House">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:onProperty>
          <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.example.org/houses#hasPart"/>
        </owl:onProperty>
        <owl:onClass rdf:resource="http://www.example.org/houses#Room"/>
        <owl:minQualifiedCardinality rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#nonNegativeInteger"
        >2</owl:minQualifiedCardinality>
      </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.example.org/houses#hasPart"/>
        <owl:someValuesFrom>
          <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.example.org/houses#Garden"/>
        </owl:someValuesFrom>
      </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.example.org/houses#hasPart"/>
        <owl:onClass>
          <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.example.org/houses#Kitchen"/>
        </owl:onClass>
        <owl:qualifiedCardinality rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#nonNegativeInteger"
        >1</owl:qualifiedCardinality>
      </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.example.org/houses#Chair"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.example.org/houses#Table"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.example.org/houses#Kitchen">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.example.org/houses#hasPart"/>
        <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.example.org/houses#Table"/>
      </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.example.org/houses#hasPart"/>
        <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.example.org/houses#Chair"/>
      </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
  </owl:Class>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: Your ontology allows the unintuitive statements that a house consists of other houses, or a garden consists of kitchens, etc. So, while you take care of something that was not asked (property cardinalities), you do not provide a solution to the question, but you rather obscure the issue of one or many hasPart properties. So, if you don't improve your answer, it should be downvoted.

Comment: @gwag Well, the tooltip for the downvote button says "this answer is not useful".  I hope that this is useful, even if it doesn't completely answer the question yet.  In OWL, it's not all the unintuitive that something might be related to something else that we hadn't been expecting, because OWL makes the open world assumption.  Nonetheless, your point is a good one, and alibenmessaoud might want that houses are only have parts of those types, and that can be achieved with a “House **subClassOf** (hasPart **only** (Kitchen **or** Room **or** Garden))” axiom.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: @gwag In general, OWL ontologies serve a different purpose than UML diagrams.  If we do have an axiom like “House **subClassOf** (hasPart **only** HousePart),”, and then see an axiom like “house73 hasPart house89”, then we don't automatically get an inconsistency.  Rather, we infer that house89 has (in addition to any other types it might have) the type HousePart.  We only get an inconsistency if we also have the axiom somewhere (declared or inferred) that House and HousePart are disjoint classes.   You're absolutely right that I've added some interpretation to the answer here;  the reason…

Comment: @gwag being that I think the question is a bit underspecified, and with some experience modeling domains in OWL (which admittedly differs from modeling in UML), I'm trying to illustrate enough of the possible things that OP might have been _trying_ to do, so that there's enough answer to work from in actually doing it.

Comment: Although the question did not address the issue of cardinality constraints, it brought up a very good point: is it possible to have a single generic composition relationship in an ontology, or do we rather need to define domain-specific composition relationships? Your afterthought to add an allValuesFrom restriction doesn't help to answer this question. So, please extend your answer to address this main issue. Otherwise, it's not helpful, but confusing.

Comment: @gwag The allvaluesfrom restriction addresses the unintuitive possibility that you mentioned in a comment; it ensures that every part of house is either a room, kitchen or garden.

Comment: I tried to wrap up our answers in an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the range of such a `composedBy` property should be a union.

Since you have two different compositions in the UML class model, you may have to define two different OWL properties, like `houseComposedBy` and `kitchenComposedBy`.

As you have suggested in your comment, in principle, it's also an option to use XML namespaces for getting different names for these different `composedBy` OWL properties (like the qualified names `house:composedBy` and `kitchen:composedBy`). In fact this corresponds to UML properties, which are always in the namespace defined by their (domain) class. So you would have to declare as many namespaces as you have classes that are the domain of a `composedBy` property.

**Edit**: I'll try to wrap up the two answers of Joshua Taylor and myself.

1. UML does not have a generic composition relationship, but rather class-specific *isComposedOf* (or *hasPart*) properties, which are defined in the namespace provided by their (domain) class. Therefore, it's an option to translate such UML properties into corresponding OWL properties, which encode their namespace either implicitly in the property name, or explicitly with an XML namespace.
2. A second approach, pointed out in the answer by Joshua Taylor is based on the fact that OWL properties are generic (not restricted to a specific domain class) by default. This allows to define a generic *hasPart* property. However, for obtaining the same range constraints that we have in our UML class model, we have to define corresponding `allValuesFrom` restrictions on our generic *hasPart* property. In addition to these `allValuesFrom` restrictions, which are essential for the translation, we could also define cardinality restrictions corresponding to the multiplicity constraints defined in our UML class model (if there are any).

Comment: Can I use namespaces for example, house:ComposedBy & kitchen:ComposedBy ?? So I have to declare some entities??

Comment: Who has down-voted my answer without explaining it in a comment? The same person who has deleted his down-voted answer?

Comment: It wasn't I that downvoted, but one possibility for a downvote here is that while it's true that the range of the property could be a union class here, if the actual problem that @alibenmessaoud is trying to say that a house must have (e.g.) at least one of each of these things, then unionof isn't really going to help; some existential restictions would be needed.

Comment: But @alibenmessaoud isn't saying anything about such multiplicity constraints, so this is your own addition to the original question.

Comment: Since I marked composition in UML relations, @Joshua is right.

Comment: No, your compositions above don't specify any multiplicity, neither at the component side nor at the aggregate side (so you don't prevent your houses having more than one kitchen). In general multiplicity at the aggregate side can be either `1` or `0..1`.